# highcharts not rendering with updated data

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple line chart. But the chart seems not to be rendering with the updated data after the first click.

I click the button first time then I update the data in database. When I click the button again, the latest data is not rendered to the chart. I did a print line on what is the chartData is. Its showing the old data.

I couldn't figure out whats the problem. Need some help here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function renderChart(divId, chartType, chartTitle, chartData, categories){
        console.log(chartData);
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(chartData);
            var cat = jQuery.parseJSON(categories);

                var options = createOption(divId, chartType, chartTitle, cat);
                options.series = data;
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        }

        function createOption(divId, chartType, chartTitle, categories){
                var options = {
                colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
                chart: {
                        backgroundColor: {
                            linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                        stops: [
                                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                                [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
                        ]
                        },
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
                        plotShadow: true,
                        plotBorderWidth: 1,
                        renderTo: divId,
                        type: chartType
                },
                title: {
            text: 'Fruit Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruits Eaten'
            }
        },
                series: []
            };

           return options;
       }

   </script>

     <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px">  
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
 </h:panelGrid> 
 <p:commandButton styleClass="commandButton" value="This" id="btnThis" process="@form" update="grid"   
        actionListener="#{pc_Test.doLoadChartDataAction}" 
        oncomplete="renderChart('container','line','Sample Chart','${pc_Test.w_test.chartData}', '${pc_Test.w_test.categories}');"/>
```

**Data**

```
Initial data
    APPLES      BANANAS     ORANGES
Anne    1       0       4
Billy   5       7       5


Updated data
    APPLES      BANANAS     ORANGES
Anne    1       0       4
Billy   5       7       10
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Do you have this live? Also, please show data sample.

Comment: @PawełFus No error in the console. Sorry I don't have it LIVE. For the first time when I click the button, the chartData print line is empty. After I re-launch the page and click the button, the chartData printed out [{"name":"Anne","data":[1,0,4]},{"name":"Billy","data":[5,7,5]}] and the chart is rendered. After that I update the data in the database and go back to the page and click on the button. The chartData is still the old data.

Comment: But when you refresh page you have updated data? In that case, `        oncomplete="renderChart('container','line','Sample Chart','${pc_Test.w_test.chartData}', '${pc_Test.w_test.categories}');"/>
` line with variable `${pc_test.w_test.chartData}` isn't updated. Probably you need to update that element, or use some AJAX.